# Correct way to apply gradients in TF2 custom training loop with multiple Keras models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6, tensorflow2.0

I am working to implement a custom training loop with GradientTape involving multiple Keras models.
I have 3 networks, `model_a`, `model_b`, and `model_c`. I have created a list to hold their `trainbale_weights` as:

```
trainables = list() 
trainables.append(model_a.trainable_weights) # CovNet 
trainables.append(model_b.trainable_weights) # CovNet 
trainables.append(model_c.trainable_weights) # Fully Connected Network
```

I then calculate loss and try to apply gradients as:

```
loss = 0.
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
for x, y in train_dataset:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = ...
        loss = ... # custom loss function!
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainables))
```

But I get a following error I am not sure where's the mistake:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'
```

If I iterate over gradients and trainables and then apply gradients it works but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
for i in range(len(gradients)):
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients[i], trainables[i]))
```

Comment: The problem is that `tape.gradient` expects `trainables` to be a flat list of trainable variables. Does `trainables = model_a.trainable_weights + model_b.trainable_weights + model_c.trainable_weights` solve the problem?

Comment: Nope. It throws `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error.

Comment: Where does this happen, exactly? I am afraid this might be another problem

Comment: when calling 'optimizer.apply_gradients'

Comment: Do you use the redefined `trainables` both in `tape.gradient` and `optimizer.apply_gradients`?

Comment: If by redefined you mean as `trainables = model_a.trainable_weights + model_b.trainable_weights + model_c.trainable_weights`. Then, yes.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a reproducible snippet?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback and a reproducible code?

Comment: `trainables = model_a.trainable_weights + model_b.trainable_weights + model_c.trainable_weights`, solved the issue. @rvinas. I missed something earlier I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `tape.gradient` expects `trainables` to be a flat list of trainable variables rather than a list of lists. You can solve this issue by concatenating all the trainable weights into a flat list:

```
trainables = model_a.trainable_weights + model_b.trainable_weights + model_c.trainable_weights
```